# How to retrieve object's text onClickListener?

Tags: view

How to retrieve text from a view object?
For example, I have a button which has some text and `onclick` of the button. I want to retrieve the text in `onClickListener` method..

Comment: Give us a clue, e.g. tell us what you're talking about.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: view [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338782/how-do-i-get-a-string-from-the-onclicklistener-view-android?rq=1) SO thread.

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this:-

```
   Button button= new Button(context);
        button.setText(R.string.uploadImage);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Button b = (Button) v;
            String buttonText = b.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(context, buttonText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript language.

```
 <script>
 function display(elem) {
   var e = elem;
   alert(e.innerHTML); // or e.value for input type="button"
 }
 </script>
 <button onclick="display(this)">button ;]</button>
```